# SQL Server 2008 'sp_syspolicy_purge_history' Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What does this built-in function do?  What is the "history" that it is deleting?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795279.aspx)? Does it not answer your question?

Comment: Neither the question nor the given answer are difficult, ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhethrocial.  It's a quick question on a very specific part of SQL Server and, as seen in the only answer given, has a quick answer.  That meets all of the criteria of this good site.

Comment: The fact that this question pops up as one of the top few results of google makes it valuable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sp_syspolicy_purge_history is used by Policy Based Management in SQL server to clear out the policy evaluation history.

**Extract from** [SQLServerPedia](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/syspolicy_purge_history-what-is-it/)

SQL Server 2008 introduced a new feature called Policy Based Management. A Policy can be something like xp_cmdshell should not be enabled on an instance. When a policy runs it stores the results in MSDB. Over a period of time, this may will cause unnecessary data getting piled up in MSDB. ***The job syspolicy_purge_history prunes the data older than the the days defined in HistoryRetentionInDays property of Policy Management***.

Comment: You can see what the instance's policies are, and the histories of them being executed (the history being purged by this job), using SQL Server Management Studio:  under the "Management" folder, then the "Policy Management" folder, then the 'Policies' folder, you can right click a policy and “View History” for a policy or a group of policies. This will provide information on execution date, policy name, targets, details and messages.  See http://blogs.extremeexperts.com/2011/01/13/sql-server-policy-history-and-metadata/